# Change scrollbar position without changing text direction

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using react and I have a problematic design using `textarea` tag. Right now it looks like this:
[image: text area problems]

I want to move the scrollbar to the right, without changing the text direction (rtl).
I'm using `TextareaAutosize` component (MUI). I tried many solutions but none of them moves the scrollbar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used `'\u202E'` (force `rtl`) at the beginning of the text, and set the whole `textarea` to be `ltr`. That moved the scrollbar to the right side, and the text-direction stayed `rtl`.
I also needed to set `text-align:right`, so the text will float to the right direction.

Works!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this css.

```
    <style>
        body {
            text-align: center;
        }
          
          
        /* Set the style of container
            div element */
        .Container{
            height: 150px;
            width: 250px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            background-color: green;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        /* Set the effects to the division
            named content */
        .Content{
            height: 200px;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
          
        /* Designing for scroll-bar */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar {
            width: 6px;
        }
      
        /* Track */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
            background: gainsboro;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
      
        /* Handle */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
            background: black;
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
      
        /* Handle on hover */
        ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
            background: #555;
        }
    </style>

and here is the usage.
  
    <div class="Container">
        <div class="Content">
            some text ...
        </div>
    </div>
```